# Android change navigation bar color when keyboard UP

Tags: android, colors, navbar, navigationbar

In my app I need to change the bottom navigation bar color to always use the apps's style. I am already using the android:navigationBarColor to the desired color, but once the keyboard appears, the navBar automatically changes to BLACK instead of my color.

```
<item name="android:navigationBarColor">@color/theme_color</item>
```

Before keyboard appears

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fuZUI.png)

After keyboard appears

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RHWOG.png)